# JAVA : Does variables use static binding or dynamic binding?

Tags: java

The result of this  code is different depend on type of reference variable does this mean variables (int a) are bounded in static way

```
class A{
    int a = 10;
}
public class Main extends A {
    int a = 30;         
    public static void main(String[] args){             
        A m = new Main();
        System.out.println("A : " + m.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you shadowing the original value of a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not just like `static` or `dynamic binding`. There is no `polymorphism` for `fields` in Java, only for `methods`.

Variables decisions are always taken at `compile-time`.

So, during the `upcasting` base class variable will be taken.

Comment: This is what iam asking , does it means variables are always static biding or does biding is a term only for polymorphism

Comment: yeah. understand.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `m` you have declared is of type `A` so the output would be `10`. Instead if you have initialized `m` as `Main m = new Main();`, then the output would have been `30`. This is because, the object is of type `Main` and since `Main` also has a field `a`, this would override the parent field `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two object's type (`A, Main`) both from them have their own meaning for a variable `a`, so when your variable m has type `A` you get value `10` and if variable m has type `Main` you will get value `30`.